How to send a message from a text field by pressing a button on the system's keyboard?
I make chat screen. There is no send message button near the text field in the design. How can I send a message from a text field by pressing a button on the system's keyboard (like this green button on screen)? I use TextFormField widget for entering the text.


To send a message from the TextFormField on the keyboard button press, you can make use of the onFieldSubmitted property in the TextFormField widget. This triggers when the user presses the keyboard action button (like the green "send" button). Here’s a basic approach:
TextFormField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintText: "Type a message",
  ),
  onFieldSubmitted: (message) {
    if (message.isNotEmpty) {
      // Implement the logic to send the message here
      print("Message sent: $message");
    }
  },
  textInputAction: TextInputAction.send, // Sets the button to a 'send' icon
)


You can achieve the Send action  by using TextInputAction.send
TextFormField(
  textInputAction: TextInputAction.send,
  onFieldSubmitted: (value) {
    // Handle the action
  },
)


You can use this code below. You can change the Icon using TextInputAction.done. Use onFieldSubmitted: (value){} to get value
TextFormField(
  maxLines: 1,
  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.displaySmall!.copyWith(
        fontSize: 12.sp,
      ),
  textAlign: TextAlign.start,
  textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
  onChanged: (value) {
    //Handle onchange
  },
  onFieldSubmitted: (value){
   //Handle when the keyboard done Icon is clicked
   },
  autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
);

